# List in C using (void *)

Tags: c, list, linked-list

Task: Create List in C (C++) using this header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const unsigned int N = 100;
const short ListOk = 0;
const short ListNotMem = 1;
const short ListEmpty = 2;
const short ListFull = 3;

typedef void * base;
typedef struct element * ptrel;
typedef struct element {
    base data;
    ptrel next;
} element;
typedef struct{
    ptrel Start;
    ptrel ptr;
    unsigned int N;
} List;

static short ListError;

void InitList(List *L);
void PutList(List *L, base E);
void GetList(List *L, base *E);
void ReadList(List *L, base *E);
int EmptyList(List *L);
int FullList(List *L);
unsigned int Count(List *L);
void BeginPtr(List *L);
void EndPtr(List *L);
void MovePtr(List *L);
void MoveTo(List *L, unsigned int n);
void ClearList(List *L);
void CopyList(List *L1, List *L2);
```

So, this is what I already wrote:

```
#include "list.h"

void InitList(List *L) {
    L->Start = (ptrel)malloc(sizeof(element));

    if (L->Start == NULL) {
        ListError = ListNotMem;
        return;
    } 

    L->ptr = L->Start;
    L->ptr->next = NULL;
    ListError = ListOk;
}

void PutList(List *L, base E) {
    ptrel tmp = (ptrel)malloc(sizeof(element));

    if (tmp == NULL) {
        ListError = ListNotMem;
        return;
    } 
    if (Count(L) == L->N) {
        ListError = ListFull;
        free(tmp);
        return;
    }

    tmp->data = E;
    tmp->next = L->ptr->next;
    L->ptr->next = tmp;

    L->ptr = L->ptr->next;
}

void GetList(List *L, base *E) {

    if (L->Start == NULL) {
        ListError = ListEmpty;
        return;
    }

    *E = L->ptr->next->data;
    L->ptr->next = L->ptr->next->next;
}
```

And now I have some questions:

1. How can I use `PutList` in main program? What is 2nd parameter? For example, if I want to put 5 in list, should I use additional variable? Like this: `x = 5; PutList(&l, (base)x)`. Right?
2. How can I use `GetList`? Again, what is 2nd parameter? `(base)&x` or what?

Comment: Unrelated: If you think type-defing pointers to something that no longer resembles a pointer in any situation *except* hiding a pointer as an opaque "handle" is somehow bringing clarity to your code, you could not possibly be more wrong. Most engineers *want* to see the asterisks. That said, pick a language: C or C++, and drop the other tag.

Comment: @WhozCraig you said about `void * base`, right? that's not my whim, this is task.
I dropped c++ tag.

Comment: About *all* of them. Apart from an opaque handle being used to hide indirection in an API, the only reason for code of the form `typedef Type *ptrType;` is to prevent an accidental declaration in a multi-variable list. I.e. `Type* a,b;` does not declare two pointers, while `ptrType a,b;` does. But that is a weak-at-best reason since it is almost assured the code won't *compile* correctly if you make the `Type* a,b;` mistake, then use `b` as a pointer-to `Type` somewhere. Its just a bad habit that actually makes code *harder* to read. Sorry if it is is a pre-exiting requirement for you. ouch.

Comment: @WhozCraig : you couldn't be more right. I've been working with Glib recently and it's really confusing to see `gpointer`s instead of `void*`s everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're right, in `PutList` the second parameter is supposed to be **a pointer to the data you want to put**. So, in your example, if the data you want to save is a number, you'd need to point to it. But notice that your implementation doesn't seem to reserve memory, so you'd have to do that yourself.
2. The second parameter ot `GetList` is **a pointer to a pointer to the result**. When you call `GetList`, it's not set yet. `GetList` will set it for you.

Example:

```
int x = 8;
List l;
PutList(l, &x);  // put a pointer to x into the list
int *y;          // y isn't set yet.
GetList(l, &y);  // now, y points to x
printf("x is %d. y points to %d.\n", x, *y);
```

Hopefully that helps!